# Camping model ignores association

Tags: ruby, activerecord, camping

```
module App::Models
  class Team < Base
    has_many :players
    [...]
  end

  class Player < Base
    belongs_to :team
  end
```

When calling `@team.players` (or `@player.team`):

```
NoMethodError at /team/red
undefined method `players' for [#<App::Models::Team (...)>]:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you're calling `players` on an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation. You don't actually have *one* Team, you have a query of several teams. Simply append `.first` to your definition of `@team` to get the first team:

```
class TeamX
  def get(name)
    @team = Team.where(:name => name).first
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, well found! Considering that wasn't the question at all, but exactly the problem, well done! Also, I'm a bit embarrassed that I made such a stupid mistake. Well, thanks!